# Fast way of summing up elements in one array by checking condition in second array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I have following three arrays

```
a = array([4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 6])
b = array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
c = array([0,0,0,0,0])
```

I want to sum all elements in `a` for all elements in `b`. For example i want following array.

```
c = array([4,4,3+5+5,4+6,5+6])
```

I can do this exercise by running a `for loop` as follows

```
loop_array = scipy.unique(b)
for i in loop_array:
    c[i]=sp.sum(a[b==i])
```

Since my original `a` and `b` arrays are very big, in the order of million, I cannot use `for loop`. Is there any faster way to solve this problem. Any array operation will be preferable if possible.

Comment: Is `b` always sorted?

Comment: `np.add.reduceat(a, np.flatnonzero(np.r_[1, np.diff(b)]))`

Comment: `b` is always sorted. @Divakar

Comment: @ZAK Then, use `np.add.reduceat`. Paul Panzer's suggestion would be a good start.

Comment: @ZAK Does your `b` by any chance run through a range of ints as it does in the example?

Comment: Yes it's range of integers. Thanks for your code by the way. @PaulPanzer

Comment: In that case `np.bincount(b, a)` may be even faster. Returns `float`s, though.

Comment: Since I don't have any issue with float's output, I think `np.bincount(b,a)` is a better choice for me. Thanks for your kind help @PaulPanzer

Comment: @ZAK You are welcome. One-liners are free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster, though it requires more memory for auxiliary arrays

```
slices1 = np.insert(np.nonzero(np.diff(b))[0]+1, 0, 0)
slices2 = np.insert(np.nonzero(np.diff(b))[0]+1, len(slices1)-1, len(b))
c = [np.sum(a[j[0]:j[1]]) for j in zip(slices1, slices2)]
```